# Using django annotate to work with percentage

Tags: django, filter, django-queryset

I'm creating a filter by percentage. When I put X (percent), it list all objects that attends.
This code below works.

```py
def my_example(self, percent):
    from models import Product
    return Product.objects.filter(amount=((percent * F("capacity")) / 100))
```

But I want to improve. My challenge is to use django annotate. I'm tryng something like this:

```py
 pct = Product.objects.annotate(pct=(percent * F("capacity") / 100)).filter(pct="amount")
```

Someone has any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are quite close, in order to reference a field, you need to use [**`F`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F), so you can filter with:

```
from django.db.models import F

pct = Product.objects.annotate(
    pct=percent * F('capacity') / 100
).filter(pct=F('amount'))
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you